# stop/reduce/mitigate global warming

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> If we work together, we can (stop/reduce/mitigate) global warming.

Which word is better?

Comment: Well is your goal to stop, reduce, or mitigate?

Comment: Your English teacher wants you to choose "reduce", if we reduce global warming we are slowing it down and preventing global temperatures from rising/increasing even further.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Global warming shouldn't be *stopped* — if it were, temperatures would plummet globally to the negatives, killing off most organisms. When we talk about **reducing the effect** or **mitigating** *global warming*, we're talking about controlling the [enhanced greenhouse effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_effect#:%7E:text=Strengthening%20of%20the%20greenhouse%20effect%20through%20human%20activities%20is%20known%20as%20the%20enhanced%20(or%20anthropogenic)%20greenhouse%20effect).

You can go for any words along the lines of mitigation, but just remember that global warming ought not to be **stopped**, but rather **managed**.